# Images through XML into to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xml, image

I have a folder of images, these images need to display on a HTML page I'm using a excel spreadsheet exported to XML which is imported into HTML using Javascript: (copied and pasted from w3schools).

What I need to do is get the images from the images folder using XML and display it in between h2 and h3.

How do I do this and what would it look like in the XML file and Javascript below?
Each div (below) then needs to be a link to different pages?

Also the items on the XML needs to be indexable/searchable I have google custom site search.

Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","cdcat.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;


var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
 document.write("<div  class=\"feat_product\"><h2>");
 document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
 document.write("</h2><h3>");
 document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
 document.write("</h3></div>");
 }
</script>
```

Comment: I believe that this code you copied from "the w3c" is probably from w3schools which is not affiliated with the W3C in any way, shape or form.

Comment: @Rob yes you are correct. Amended.

Answer (score 0):

I will not write your code for you, but explain the approach:

You need to use `img` elements and set the `src` attribute to the public path the images are exposed on. This is in javascript.

In your XML, for each `CD` element you will need to pass in the image path as well to be consumed by the javascript.

Comment: Thanks, but I have no idea what that means. I'm a new to this.

Comment: @DigitalRobotGorilla - I don't know what you don't understand. You are new to what? Javascript? HTML? XML? All of them?

Comment: @DigitalRobotGorilla - You need to look up what `element` and `attribute` mean then.

Comment: @DigitalRobotGorilla - Then this is far beyond anything we can help you with on SO.

Comment: I was hoping it would be a quick fix, but I guess not. I'm a third of a way out of 1000+ items manually inserting each item line by line on a static website and then came across XML/Javascript. Got most of it just the images part I couldn't figure out.